# iPhone XIB quickly grows to huge size

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, png, xib

I used to have a very small/simple XIB file.
Something has caused it to quickly grow to over 500k.

The only graphics in it are 3 small PNG files (about 4k each).

Here's some of the XIB.  Any idea on what is causing this size increase?

```
   <string key="NSFrame">{{0, 44}, {320, 416}}</string>
                        <reference key="NSSuperview" ref="391473517"/>
                        <object class="NSColor" key="IBUIBackgroundColor">
                            <int key="NSColorSpace">10</int>
                            <object class="NSImage" key="NSImage">
                                <int key="NSImageFlags">469473884</int>
                                <string key="NSSize">{256, 256}</string>
                                <object class="NSMutableArray" key="NSReps">
                                    <bool key="EncodedWithXMLCoder">YES</bool>
                                    <object class="NSArray">
                                        <bool key="EncodedWithXMLCoder">YES</bool>
                                        <integer value="0"/>
                                        <object class="NSBitmapImageRep">
                                            <object class="NSData" key="NSTIFFRepresentation">
                                                <bytes key="NS.bytes">
anB3/3Byef91d33/dHZ8/2psc/9sbnX/Z2p0/3N1fP9qbXf/cXN6/2psdf9wcnv/dnd9/25xe/9ucHf/
cnB3/2ptd/92eH//a254/3Fzev9sb3n/cHJ5/25wd/9ucHf/cHN9/25wd/9wcnn/dnh8/2xudf93eX//
bm13/2ptd/9sb3n/bG51/3V3ff97fYP/YmVu/25xe/9sb3n/c3Z//2psc/9zdXz/cHN9/2dqcf9qbHP/
CmVu/2dqdP9nanH/am13/2xvef91eIH/Z2p0/25xe/91d33/bG51/25wd/92eHz/dXd9/29xdf9ucHf/
fHl9/2xudf9ucHf/bG95/3Bzff9sb3n/bnF7/3l7gf9zdn//c3Z//3N2f/91eIH/c3V8/3Byef9nanT/
zXd9/2dqdP9ucXv/dXd9/3N2f/9zdXz/Z2px/2xudf9ucXv/am13/3Bzff9zdXz/cHN9/2psc/9qbXf/
AbG51/2Jlbv9qbXf/aGp0/2hqcP9rbnX/cnV//29yfP9ucXv/bnF7/25xe/9zdn//bXB1/2xvef9qbXb/
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information on your specific XIB file? What sort of control has the image set? Is this a released or beta version of Xcode/Interface Builder? Generally XIB files should not contain images, so you might consider reporting a bug to Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Happens to me as well for no apparent reason.

Comment: I believe it's related to having images in the .xib. I'm going to test by removing the images I have embedded and see if the size reduces.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution that fixed it for me had to do with the class method on UIColor called viewFlipsideBackgroundColor. In my xib I set the background color on a UIImage to be this pattern, and I guess xcode then throws a tiff representation in the xib that is 320x460. As soon as I changed this color, the xib size dropped 800kb.

Did you include any patterns in your xib? If so, try applying them programatically.

Answer (score 0):

They might have been PNG files that you dragged in, but the xib contains TIFF data:

> ```
> <object class="NSData" key="NSTIFFRepresentation">
> ```

You should remove the images from your nib and include the PNG files in your application bundle and refer to them by name from your code.

(That's assuming, of course, that the small snippet of xib you showed is actually relevant to the problem, and not something completely innocent.)

Comment: I think it might be a bug with Apple. After removing the images, the xib was still huge. I also had the images in my app bundle to begin with.

Comment: @Mark: I recommend opening the xib in a text editor and looking around to see what's so huge in there. It might be the same problem, or it might be something different (or a different, possibly newer, variation on the same problem).

Comment: I posted an answer with what I think the issue is. Basically I removed views until the size went down. But my xibs look just like the one in the question.